# Logstash Grok match to last index unti begin of UserAgent

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have this log message:

```
"sid-cmascioieiow89322&New*Sou,th%20Skvn%20and%20ir&o,n%20Age,Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CHM-U01 Build/HonorCHM-U01) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

And the pattern:

```
"(?[^&])&(?[^,]),%{GREEDYDATA:User_Agent}"
```

The problem is p2 sometimes contains zero or one or more then one comma. I want to match to the last comma before `UserAgent` because `UserAgent` some time contains commas.

This is the grok debugger link: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Now:

```
{
    "p1": [
        "sid-cmascioieiow89322"
    ],
    "p2": [
        "New*Sou"
    ],
    "User_Agent": [
        "th%20Skvn%20and%20iro,n%20Age,Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CHM-U01 Build/HonorCHM-U01) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    ]
}
```

I want like this:

```
{
    "p1": [
        "sid-cmascioieiow89322"
    ],
    "p2": [
        "New*Sou,th%20Skvn%20and%20ir&o,n%20Age"
    ],
    "User_Agent": [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CHM-U01 Build/HonorCHM-U01) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    ]
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the `p2` before the user agent always contains a string of chars other than whitespace? Try using `(?<p2>\S*)`

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of string that you want to capture into `p2` part has no whitespaces. Thus, instead of a `[^,]*` pattern that matches *any* zero or more chars other than `,` you may use `\S*` - any 0+ **non-whitespace** chars as many as possible, thus `\S*,` will match the comma that is the last in the streak of non-whitespace chars.

```
(?<p1>[^&]*)&(?<p2>\S*),%{GREEDYDATA:User_Agent}
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[This is how this regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/9koavh/1) your log data:[image]

See the Grok demo screenshot:
[image]